# TypeError: sendTrade() missing 1 required positional argument: from class function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to access a function inside the class which houses the Discord bot. Getting

> TypeError: sendTrade() missing 1 required positional argument: 'valuta'.

`MyClient.sendTrade()` is called from within a loop in another function which is run inside a thread.

```
def monitor():
    if stuff here is true:
        MyClient.sendTrade(pris, volym, befattning, getTicker(isin), namn, valuta)

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')
    async def sendTrade(self, pris, volym, befattning, ticker, namn, valuta):
        id = 930909133224435737
        channel = MyClient.get_channel(id)
        await channel.message.send("" + str(befattning) + " köpte " + str(ticker) + " för " + str(float(pris)*float(volym)/1000000) + " M" + valuta +" i " + namn + " för " + str(pris) + " per aktie")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=clearLst).start()
    Thread(target=monitor).start()
    client = MyClient()
    client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `sendTrade` as if it is a static method (on the class), but the method itself is declared as an instance method, so you should call it on `client` and not on `MyClient`.

Make sure that `client` is initialised before accessing it.

There are multiple ways to do that. For instance, you could make `monitor` a method of the class, and then you have the instance as `self`.

Comment: Thank you. How would I do that from inside the monitor() function?

Comment: Create the instance when it doesn't exist yet, otherwise use the existing instance?

Comment: Passing client as an argument to monitor then use it gives a tracemalloc error. I don't know if that is what you mean by use the existing instance.

Comment: Why not make monitor a method of the class? I cannot really propose code, because what you provided is not complete. For instance `self.user` is nowhere initialised, and is `get_channel` really a static method of the class (it is not defined), ...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I eneded up adding it to the class and now it works, thank you.